# Storing client secrets for desktop apps particularly electron/cli apps

Tags: firebase, electron, firebase-tools

[image]

I tried to lookup how firebase cli handles client secrets.
Can somebody explain what that means.

I have a electron app. I need users to login and keep those access token offline so that they need not login again. I have it all figured out but the problem is with storing client secrets. Am I in the right direction or is there any problem??

Update: [Github firebase link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/lib/api.js#L80)

Comment: These are not secrets, but values that your client-side code needs to connect to the correct Firebase backend. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public. But I'm not completely sure what that `clientSecret` is there. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the link

Comment: @PurTahan I kinda figured a way. Just let me know what you guys think about this. using normal http auth by serving a page and then storing the access token on the client so that if needed later can be used. In my case I need to send emails from the logged in user's profile. So once logged in I will store the access_token and all the data in some file and use that with gmail api to send email. Till now this is what seems totally safe to me

Comment: @PurTahan what's your exact situation?